# Time-Discretize a Linear Quadratic OCP (Bolza Function)

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I'm trying to formulate an optimal control problem based off of this given Minimum-Time Cost Function:
$$J(t_f)=\frac{1}{2}[x(t_f)-x_{des}(t_f)]^TP_f[x(t_f)-x_{des}(t_f)] + \frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^{t_f}(1+[x^t(t)Qx(t)+u^T(t)Ru(t)])dt$$
$$ \text{ where } x=\begin{bmatrix}V\\\gamma\\h\\r\end{bmatrix}P_f\in\mathbb{R}^{4x4}, Q\in\mathbb{R}^{4x4}, Q_x\in\mathbb{R}^{4x4}, R=\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } u=\theta=\text{Pitch angle}$$

I would like to minimize the time for a small RC aircraft to go from takeoff at time $t_0$ to cruise in the shortest amount of time $t_f$. I think that there are basically 2 approaches to solving this.

1. I can use the ACADO Matlab toolkit to solve the function in this form. I've tried doing this and I cannot seem to understand ACADO well enough to solve it.
2. First time-discretize the cost function to put the function in a form which can be solved using another Matlab toolkit such as YALMIP.

Seeing as I've failed on approach #1, I would like to try approach #2. However, I do not understand how to time-discretize this function. I've tried looking through textbooks for how to solve these problems, but I cannot find any text that gives a method to discretize a function like this into a form which can be solved with a solver.

I have initial and final constraints, and have the state space model, but do not really know how to proceed from here
$$\dot{x}=\begin{bmatrix}\dot{V}=\frac{1}{m}(Tcos(u-\gamma)-D-mgsin(\gamma)\\\dot{\gamma}=\frac{1}{mV}(Tsin(u-\gamma)+L-mgcos(\gamma)\\\dot{h}=Vsin(\gamma)\\\dot{r}=Vcos(\gamma)\end{bmatrix}$$

I've read that I may need to solve for the Hamiltonian, but I don't understand why, and still would not understand how to proceed solving the problem in matlab once I would solve for it.

Comment: I assume $u=T$?

Comment: u is the pitch angle $\theta$

Comment: So $\dot{x}$ is not a function of $u$?

Comment: I suppose it could be in that $\theta = \gamma + \alpha$ where it can reasonably be assumed that $\alpha$ will be constant for this problem. Doing so would simply replace my state variable $\gamma$ though, so perhaps this is not the best way to go about this problem? I currently have my thrust modeled as $T=0.5*\rho V^2SC_D$ where $C_D$ is a function of $\alpha$

Comment: ^Actually disregard that comment. I updated my problem statement, replacing $\alpha$ with $\theta-\gamma$ to better see the relation

Comment: You might be able to use [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle) to solve for $u(t)$ given a value for $t_f$ and then optimize the resulting $J(t_f)$ with respect to $t_f$. However your problem formulation is still a bit odd, because your terminal cost as a function of $x_{des}(t_f)$ should not matter if you also have terminal equality constraints.

Comment: @kwin van der veen  thank you for the help! One aspect I still do not understand, is that even when trying to solve this problem using existing toolkits such as TomLab, ACADO, and GPOPS my problem is still coming back with invalid results. TomLab has a minimum time to climb problem script for a full-scale hypersonic aircraft. When I manipulated this script for a small RC-aircraft (which greatly simplifies the problem), the results were invalid. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my ODE model. Is there anything that strikes you incorrect about my state space?

Comment: To follow up on this, TomLab has an example to do exactly what I want to do for a hypersonic aircraft at this link: https://tomopt.com/docs/propt/tomlab_propt068.php 
In the example, the ODE is given as:
$$dot(h) == v.*sin(fpa)$$
$$dot(v) == ((T.*cos(aalpha)-D)./m - mmu.*sin(fpa)./(Re+h).2$$
$$dot(fpa) == (T.sin(aalpha)+L)./(m.v)+cos(fpa).(v./(Re+h)-mmu./(v.(Re+h).2);$$I do not understand where these values are coming from. I can't find any references which display the EOM as a function of RE, and I'm unsure if the term 'mmu' is viscosity or something else. In their script it is 0.1407e17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86094/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-rocketsocks22).